# Is there a way to put the terraform backend configuration in a module?

Tags: terraform

All my terraform files start with:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.11, < 0.12"
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "my-terraform-state"
    key     = "my-service/my-component/terraform.tfstate"
    region  = "eu-west-1"
    encrypt = "true"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
  version = ">= 1.8, < 1.9"
}
```

What I would like is something like

```
module "header" {
  source = "module-location"
  region = "eu-west-1"
  state_key = "my-service/my-component"
}
```

When I try something like this it fails with the message that the backend configuration cannot contain variables. I also read about the read-only state and noticed that it can contain variables.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a singe file called `terraform.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.11, < 0.12"
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "my-terraform-state"
    key     = "my-service/my-component/terraform.tfstate"
    region  = "eu-west-1"
    encrypt = "true"
  }
}
```

and a `provider.tf`:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
  version = ">= 1.8, < 1.9"
}
```

Place these files in the root dir. Terraform will use them and you no longer need to have those headings at the top of each file.

You can not use variables / interpolation in `terraform.tf`, as this file is used very early by terraform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But wouldn't all components share the same state file, thus losing the advantage of storing the state per component?